# 2013 search - select columns from a specific table in site collections

Tags: 2013, search, site-collection

Looking at all the new search capability in 2013 I'm thinking this should be do-able.. where as in 2010 we put it in the "too hard basket"

Basically we plan to build some site collections (project template) and each site collection will contain a list that will have columns such as project name, project manager, start date and end date. The column names and the list names will always be the same. The site collections will always be under the managed path /proj/

Now, I'd like to be able to display a page that shows the result of a query against all these site collections. So if there are 7 site collections there will be 7 results showing the columns mentioned above. I don't want to use the standard core results with a query builder using "path" as I want spefici list column values in my results rather than the normal hyperlink and synopsis

Answer (score 1):

Create a Content Type then create a set of columns for the Content Type that describes your Project content type. Then create your list using the content type and populate it. In search only search for ContentType:MyProject and you will get your result. I do this for Site Directory info all the time.

Comment: Thanks, the lists, columns etc are already in place. I now need a page (not search results web part) to list all the projects with their details as specified above. User will not be expected to provide search values but instead navigate to a page that is populated on the fly with ALL projects and their info. I'm thinking my answer may lie with managed properties, result sources and a display template but I have not done a lot in that area.

Comment: You asked for the best approach. Content Types are the way to go. Since the data is already in place you can cobble together a solution. Yes, You will have to use managed Properties and then add a Search Result web part to a page with your query. You can create a Result Source too, but all of this is simple if you start with a Content Type.